# Unable to get value between li tag

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get value between two li tags but unfortunately it is saying my undefined.

In details, I want a script which automatically clicks on next page and get your current page (on linkedin Page)

So this is what our DOM initially looks like

```
<li class="page-list">
      <ol>
            <li class="active">1</li>
            <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-2354="2354">2</button></li>
            <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-2356="2356">3</button></li>
            <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-2358="2358">4</button></li>
            <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-2360="2360">5</button></li>
            <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-2362="2362">6</button></li>
            <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-2364="2364">7</button></li>
            <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-2366="2366">8</button></li>
            <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-2368="2368">9</button></li>
            <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-2370="2370">10</button></li>
      </ol>
    </li>
```

Now to select the nested things I am doing something Like this

```
`var x = document.getElementsByClassName("page-list")[0];`
```

Value of the x on console.log is same as what is pasted above

Then I do something like this to select active class

```
x = x.querySelector('li[class="active"]')
```

this console logs this

```
<li class="active">1</li>
```

Now Here I want to get that value 1, On the inspect element of chrome, while on the linkedin page (to simulate the event) i have tried tried things like

```
currentPageValue = x.querySelector('li[class="active"]').value;
currentPageValue = x.getElementsByClassName('active')[0].innerHTML
```

These throws an error saying that cannot read property value/InnerHTML of null.

```
currentPageValue = x.getElementsByClassName('active').value
```

This shows the value of null (and many other things)

What I want to have here is the integer value (which would be 1 here) in

```
<li class="active">1</li>
```

Can anyone please help me in knowing how can I get that value?

Comment: `x.getElementsByClassName` => `document.getElementsByClassName`

Comment: Use `li.active` instead of `li[class="active"]`

Comment: `<li>` don't have `value`s they have `textContent`,`innerText`, and `innerHTML`

Comment: OP, read what @PatrickEvans mentioned.

Comment: Also if `x.querySelector('li[class="active"]')` or `x.querySelector('li.active')` end up causing you to get a `cannot read` error then there is no element with an active class in your `page-list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.querySelector('.page-list li.active').textContent` should do the trick. Provided that you call it when DOM is ready.

Or `var menu = document.querySelector('.page-list); menu.querySelector('li.active')`

```js
var menu = document.querySelector('.page-list');

console.log(
  document.querySelector('.page-list li.active').textContent,
  menu.querySelector('li.active').textContent
)
```

```html
<li class="page-list">
  <ol>
    <li class="active">1</li>
    <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-2354="2354">2</button></li>
    <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-2356="2356">3</button></li>
    <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-2358="2358">4</button></li>
    <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-2360="2360">5</button></li>
    <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-2362="2362">6</button></li>
    <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-2364="2364">7</button></li>
    <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-2366="2366">8</button></li>
    <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-2368="2368">9</button></li>
    <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-2370="2370">10</button></li>
  </ol>
</li>
```

Comment: Note since OP mentions selecting `page-list` element first, might want to modify this to also do the same. As querying the entire document might get an active li that OP didn't intend.